# Call stack is not symbolificated iOS device

Tags: ios, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqEZr.png)
Long stand by application showing this

Morethan 20 mins renderer my app showing this type of error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.